# Cannot retrieve query.start-index variable from Google Analytics Core Reporting Results JSON Object

Tags: php, json, google-analytics

I am building a Google Analytics Dashboard and have it pretty completed, but am just totally stumped on this one thing that is really hanging me up.

When I query the GA Core Reporting API for a dataset, I successfully get and am able to display results and everything works fine EXCEPT I am not able to query the JSON object for the "start-index". That is, the first row that it will display (default = 1, but GA only returns 10k rows at a time, so if you have a data set with >10k rows, this becomes critically important!).

To attempt to get this integer, I use

```
$start = $results->query.start-index;
```

and as a check to make sure I am not insane, "max-results" is right next to "start-index" in the JSON object and this works fine:

```
$max = $results->totalResults;
```

Here is the GA JSON object (per https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startIndex)

```
{
"kind": "analytics#gaData",
 "id": string,
"selfLink": string,
"containsSampledData": boolean,
"query": {
  "start-date": string,
  "end-date": string,
  "ids": string,
  "dimensions": [
    string
  ],
  "metrics": [
    string
  ],
  "sort": [
    string
  ],
  "filters": string,
  "segment": string,
  "start-index": integer,
  "max-results": integer
},
"itemsPerPage": integer,
"totalResults": integer,
"previousLink": string,
"nextLink": string,
"profileInfo": {
  "profileId": string,
  "accountId": string,
  "webPropertyId": string,
  "internalWebPropertyId": string,
  "profileName": string,
  "tableId": string
},
"columnHeaders": [
  {
    "name": string,
    "columnType": string,
    "dataType": string
  }
],
"rows": [
  [
    string
  ]
],
"totalsForAllResults": [
  {
    metricName: string,
    ...
  }
]
}
```

Help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am still not entirely sure *why* this works the way it does, but I've successfully pulled the correct start-index number using the following function:

```
function getStartIndex(&$results) {
  $query = $results->getQuery();

  foreach ($query as $paramName => $value) {
    if($paramName == "start-index")
    $startIndex = $value;
  }
  return $startIndex;
}
```

This essentially loops through the entire $query associative array until it finds one where the parameter matches "start-index" and then returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

Property names in PHP can contain neither `.` nor `-`. Your code is interpreted as a string concatenation of an array with the result of a mathematical subtraction of two strings (don't even begin to try and understand this if you don't see what I mean from that description).

PHP is actually a complete pain in the rear-end when it comes to this point, you have to force it to convert the decoded data to associative arrays instead of objects by passing `TRUE` to the second argument of `json_decode()`. You can then access the data by array key:

E.g.

```
$results = json_decode($jsonString, TRUE);
$start = $results['query']['start-date'];
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I do not use json_decode because I believe the GA API takes care of that for me (I use the $analytics->data_ga->get() function to retrieve the data). When I use something like "$foo = $results->itemsPerPage;" it works fine. The problem is getting data from that next level. Is there a way to do this in the format I am more familiar with?

Comment: OK, which class is `$analytics` an instance of (Google docs not great, don't have the time to properly dig through the code)?

Comment: I initiatie $analytics with this:      $analytics = new apiAnalyticsService($client);

Comment: @ARH3 Can you show `var_dump($results)`? Looks like it should already be an array from a cursory look at the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I figured out the answer! Will be posting as a separate answer on this question. Thanks again!

Comment: @ARH3, hi ARH3, I'm running into the same issue, can you please post the full answer, I believe it's something related to array('max-results'=> '', 'start-index'=>''). that will be highly appreciated! thanks!!!

Comment: Hi @mongotop . I posted my solution to the problem below. The entire function that I use is there... I simply pass the query results to the function and it returns the start-index. Hope it helps!

Comment: @ARH3 Thanks for your reply, Looks great! I want to know How you used the start-index parameter to iterate through the result ? Thanks again!

Comment: @mongotop I am going to answer your question below, so it is attached to the approved answer of this original question.